# apache tomcat 9.x not working with eclipse & Java 10.0.1

Tags: eclipse, java-10, tomcat9

I've installed apache-tomcat-**9.0.7** on my windows machine and have following environment configurations:

echo %JAVA_HOME%

C:\Program Files\Java\ **jdk-10.0.1**

---

echo %JRE_HOME%

C:\Program Files\Java\ **jre-10.0.1**

---

OS : **Windows 8 64-bit**

---

Eclipse Version: **Oxygen.3a** Release (4.7.3a)

---

Whenever I run `catlina.bat start` from **cmd**, server runs fine on localhost But I'm not able to get the server instance up from eclipse's server configuration.

1. Defined a new server in eclipse and added apache-tomact 9.0 instance
2. Upon clicking on start server , I get the following error:

   *-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-9.0.7\endorsed is not supported*. `Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules`.

[image: Error Screen]

Any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Found a similar discussion here : https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1092977/ , but still unresolved.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need an update that isn't on the main Oxygen site. Add `http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/oxygen/` as a URL in your **Available Software Sites** preference page and then check for updates from the **Help** menu.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/533162

Edit: this fix will be properly included in the Photon (WTP 3.10) release later this month.

Comment: kudos to you @nitind !! Issue is resolved upon installing WTP 3.9.4

Comment: This almost worked for me. For some reason, Oxygen would not auto detect the new WTP version and insisted that there was nothing new to install. I had to go through the install new software help flow to get 3.9.4. Thanks a lot nitind and @Saurabh Bhoomkar.

Comment: Same Problem. Could you let me know how to install WTP 3.9.4 @zerpsed

Comment: @Teja are you **sure** that site is in your list of update sites?

Comment: Could you please help me with this issue? I have been trying this from yesterday onwards..

Comment: I have already installed it and can see it in my eclipse market place.

Comment: @Teja this isn't available through the Marketplace.

Comment: Yes, now WTP 3.9.4 got detected and I installed on my machine. And my problem is still unresolved that, I could not start my Tomcat 8 server. It's throwing me the same error.

Comment: Does the Console view indicate an error about an endorsed libraries parameter no longer being supported?

Comment: @Teja, just saw your comment to me, looks like you got 3.9.4 installed now. After getting things in good shape, I had a few subsequent problems with wtp but not Java 10 related.

Comment: Thank You @nitind My issue got resolved with Photon update

Answer (score 10):

I had to remove that argument from the launch configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In my Eclipse Oxygen IDE, WTP version did not update as suggested by @nitind.

I figured out a fix with some trial and error as I wanted to change JRE version for Tomcat

1. To use Tomcat 8 with JRE 8
   Eclispe --> Preferences --> Server --> Runtime Environments --> Select Tomcat 8 --> Edit --> Change default JRE to JRE 8

Also change JDK version in Compiler & Project Facets

2. Eclispe --> Preferences --> Server --> Runtime Environments --> Select Tomcat 9 --> Edit --> Change default JRE to JRE 9

Also change JDK version to 9 in Compiler & Project Facets

Also need to remove -Djava.endorsed argument from "Runtime Configurations" in Project right click --> Run As --> Run Configurations --> Apache Tomcat

It will surely work! :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing  -Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed" from server config worked for me also