# Tomcat Server Not Starting from Eclipse Oxygen in Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, spring-mvc, tomcat

I added tomcat 8 and 9 both in my eclipse oxygen and tried to run Spring based Web Application on the tomcat server but its giving error in console:

**Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit**

In popup it gives the error:

**'Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem
Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start.**

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: Most of the time this is a result of an improper mapping of a servlet

Comment: The only thing I am getting in console is: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/<username>/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.

Comment: Which version of Oxygen? Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085750/ (same solution should correct cases with Java 9 as well).

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed JVM problem"? And shouldn't this new problem be a different question?

Comment: @nitind JVM problem: Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. I have fixed this

Comment: I understand which problem you fixed, I'm curious about how you fixed it. As might anyone else with this original problem.

Comment: Problem not yet fixed. I am getting this error in console .                  
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/<username>/Desktop/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.52/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.

Comment: any fix yet? I just had this issue too.

Comment: Yes its fixed. For me it was related to java version. It was Java 10 in mac. I installed 8 and it started working!!

Answer (score 0):

Please do a "ping localhost" on a terminal. if it is responding something like

ping: cannot resolve localhost: Unknown host

Chances are you don't have "127.0.0.1 localhost" line in your hosts file (/etc/hosts). So, just add it there.
Sometimes the line is there but it is still not working. The issue can be with the "Line Endings" on /etc/hosts file. Check it using Sublime (View/Line Endings). If it is set to "Mac OS" just change it to "Unix". 
After do this, try again to ping localhost. If it is going as expected just try again Running/Debugging on Server in Eclipse.