# tomcat 9.0 JVM cannot be created,fatal error occured program will quit

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am using WIndows 10 64 bit version, i installed eclipse oxygen and Tomcat (. When i try to start my tomcat an error is raised saying "JVM cannot be created. Program will exit"

```
 -startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
 --launcher.library
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108- 
 1834
 -product
 org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
 -showsplash
 org.eclipse.epp.package.common
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 --launcher.appendVmargs
 -vmargs
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
 -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
 -XX:+UseG1GC
 -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
 --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
 -Xms256m
 -Xmx1024m
 --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

What all i have tried:
changing xmx1024 to xmx512m
created a environment variable JAVA_OPTIONS with value -Xmx512M

I am currently using Java 10

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085750/ .

Comment: still no answer!

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: there isnt an answer even in the given link.. if you can help me it ll be great

Comment: Now I'm confused, because it sure looks like there is an answer there.

Comment: please do your homework and try the answer given by @nitind in its link.